# custom taxonomy archive permalink shows 404 error

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks

In my plugin I have a custom post type with a slug of 'ready-to-wear' and I have a custom taxonomy called 'seasons' associated with it.

The odd thing is that this url with query works:

`http://dev.catwalkyourself.com/ready-to-wear/?seasons=autumn-winter-2012-2013-en`

but the same one with custom permalink doesn't:

`http://dev.catwalkyourself.com/ready-to-wear/seasons/autumn-winter-2012-2013-en`

It throws a 404 error. You can try pasting the links yourself.

Here is my relevant plugin code:

Here is where the custom post type is registered

$post_types = array();

```
    $post_types['rtw'] =  $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('RTW Collections'),
            'singular_name' => __('Ready to Wear Collection'),
            'add_new' => __('Add new RTW collection'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add a new show to the RTW collection'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Collection'),
            'view_item' => __('View Collection'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Ready to Wear Collections'),
            'not_found' => __('No RTW Collections found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No RTW Collections found in trash')
        ),
        'query_var' => 'rtw_collections',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'comments'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('seasons','city'),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'ready-to-wear',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6
    );
```

Here is where the taxonomy is configured:

$taxonomies = array();

```
    $taxonomies['seasons'] = array(
        'query_var' => 'seasons',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'seasons',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'single_value' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Seasons'),
            'singular_name' => __('Season'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Season'),
            'update_item' => __('Update Season'),
            'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add or remove seasons'),
            'new_item_name' => __('Add new Season'),
            'all_items' => __('All Seasons'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Seasons'),
            'popular_items' => __('Popular Seasons'),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate Items with commas'),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from most used Seasons')
        )
    );
```

and here is the call to `register_taxonomy`:

```
foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy => $arr) {
            register_taxonomy($taxonomy, null, $arr);
        }
```

I have tried:

- Flushing the permalinks repeatedly
- Setting 'with_front' true and false repeatedly
- add flush_rewrite action to my functions.php

Unfortunately, none of these work. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by making sure that the calls to register my taxonomies were placed before the calls to registering my custom post types. Weird but it works!

Comment: OMG thank you for this!!! i was tearing my hair out. No idea why that fixed all the mysterious issues I've been having but it did. THANKS!

Comment: I swear, I have been searching for this answer for two weeks. I will be embedding the link in the comments of my code! F-YEAH!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, WP route system understands it should serve the archive, but ends up serving index.php instead. I wrote this filter to serve the correct template file instead:

```php
add_filter('template_include', function ($template) {
    global $wp;

    switch ($wp->request) {
        case 'myCategory':
            return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/archive-my-category.php';
        case 'myOtherCategory':
            return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/archive-my-other-category.php';
        default:
            return $template;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Add

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

After your `register_taxonomy()` function

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Flushing rewrite rules on every request comes with a huge performance drawback.